# Auto Complete Textbox in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I am trying to make an auto complete textbox using method mentioned in this https://github.com/Nimgoble/WPFTextBoxAutoComplete/  link.But I am unable to make it work.

My XAML code is as follows:

```
<TextBox Name="searchBox"
            Width="250"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            Text="{Binding TestText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
            behaviors:AutoCompleteBehavior.AutoCompleteItemsSource="{Binding TestItems}" 
             Margin="0,0,0,75" RenderTransformOrigin="0.86,0.706" 
        />
```

This is my Code behind code :

```
 IEnumerable<string> TestItems = new List<string>() { "John", "Mark","Doe" };
 this.DataContext= TestText;
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Please try the below code and customize the way you like

xaml code -

```
 <Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtAuto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" Margin="181,87,0,0" PreviewKeyDown="txtAuto_KeyDown" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190"/> 
    <ListBox x:Name="lblSuggestion" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="60" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="190" Margin="181,130,0,0" 
             Visibility="Collapsed" KeyDown="lblSuggestion_KeyDown"  SelectionChanged="lblSuggestion_SelectionChanged"/>

</Grid>
```

Code Behind -

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    List<string> stringCollection;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        stringCollection = new List<string>
        {
            "abc","ayr","bef","bcs","caa","lmn"

        };

        txtAuto.TextChanged += txtAuto_TextChanged;
    }

    void txtAuto_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string typedString = txtAuto.Text;

        List<string> autoList = new List<string>();

        autoList.Clear();

        foreach (string item in stringCollection)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtAuto.Text))
            {

                if (item.Contains(typedString))
                {
                    autoList.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }

        if (autoList.Count > 0)
        {
            lblSuggestion.ItemsSource = autoList;
            lblSuggestion.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else if (txtAuto.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            lblSuggestion.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            lblSuggestion.ItemsSource = null;
        }
        else
        {
            lblSuggestion.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            lblSuggestion.ItemsSource = null;
        }
    }

    void lblSuggestion_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (lblSuggestion.ItemsSource != null)
        {
            lblSuggestion.KeyDown += lblSuggestion_KeyDown;               
        }
    }

    private void txtAuto_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Down)
        {
            lblSuggestion.Focus();
        }

    }

    private void lblSuggestion_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(sender, lblSuggestion))
        {
            if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
            {
                txtAuto.Text = lblSuggestion.SelectedItem.ToString();
                lblSuggestion.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }

            if (e.Key == Key.Down)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                lblSuggestion.Items.MoveCurrentToNext();
            }
            if (e.Key == Key.Up)
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                lblSuggestion.Items.MoveCurrentToPrevious();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was trying to use that as an example. your example just show list when text box is empty. I want to Tag people so when ever a semicolon appears it should tokenize the word.I Have already done the tokeninzing work.But how will I do it here?

Comment: In the above example it shows list whenever you type the search item for example if you type "a" it will show all the items related to "a" in list box

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyViewModel {
    public IEnumerable<string> TestItems;
}
```

and in your constructor:

```
IEnumerable<string> TestItems = new List<string>() { "John", "Mark","Doe" };
this.DataContext = new MyViewModel { TestItems = TestItems };
```